# How can I return changes to a String

Tags: java, swap

How can I adjust my change method in my Changer class so that it will execute all of the added changes and return the string with the changes? I am having trouble trying to implement this in the for loop. The output should not have any accent marks over the letters.

```
public class Change {
    private char fromCharacter;
    private char toCharacter;

    public Change(char fromCharacter, char toCharacter) {
        this.fromCharacter = fromCharacter;
        this.toCharacter = toCharacter;
    }

    public String change(String characterString) {
        String newWord = characterString.replace(fromCharacter, toCharacter);
        return newWord;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Changer {
    private ArrayList<Change> changes;

    public Changer() {
        this.changes = new ArrayList<Change>();
    }

    public void addChange(Change change) {
        this.changes.add(change);
    }

    public String change(String characterString) {
        String word = "";

        for (Change change : changes) {
            word = change.change(characterString);
        }   

        return word;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Changer scandiesAway = new Changer();
        scandiesAway.addChange(new Change('ä', 'a'));
        scandiesAway.addChange(new Change('ö', 'o'));
        System.out.println(scandiesAway.change("ääliö älä lyö, ööliä läikkyy"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the `String.replaceAll()` method? Is this for an assignment?

Comment: This is the worst possible implementation if it comes to efficiency. Yes, You could use replaceAll (replace replaces just 1 occurence), but if You do replaceAll multiple times (cause of many replacements) this implementation is BAAAAAADDDDD.

Cause it is friday and I'm allready lazy, but a fan of SolR, here's an implementation for You, that will show You how it's done;)

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/2.9.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ISOLatin1AccentFilter.java

Comment: Ok, seriously: You should iterrate over characters in input string, make a switch for each character (exchanging it with non accent version) and put the exchanged into a StringBuffer/Builder

Comment: Yes this is for an assignment, I would have definitely taken another route if it was allowed.

Comment: @maslan I can't really use any switches, so should get rid of the String word = ""? I am just unsure what I would return if I don't have a variable word. How would I assign the method to a characterString variable?

Comment: @NoahKettler how about a long if? I don't understand the last question, could You clarify? :)

Comment: @maslan I was trying to describe what JSIK below. I don't know why I thought I needed an extra variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your methods as follows;

Class `Change`

```
public String change(String characterString)  {       
  return characterString.replace(fromCharacter, toCharacter);  
}
```

Class `Changer`

```
public String change(String characterString) {

    for (Change change : changes) {
        characterString = change.change(characterString);
    }

    return characterString;
}
```

Comment: This worked. I had almost exactly this before but for some reason thought I needed to include a new variable. Thanks!